# Cannot ssh login after setting firewall for xrdp

Tags: firewall, centos-8

I am trying to install xrdp on CentOS 8. I followed the tutorial on [how-to-install-xrdp-on-centos-8](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-centos-8/), and set the firewall to allow connection to 3389 from LAN (192.168.31.*) only.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --new-zone=xrdp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=xrdp --add-port=3389/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=xrdp --add-source=192.168.31.0/24 --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

But then I found that I am not able to ssh login to this pc from my laptop anymore.

```
➜  ~ ssh xxx@192.168.31.18  -vvv
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.31.18 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.31.18 [192.168.31.18] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.31.18 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.31.18 port 22: Connection refused
```

After some debugging, if I undo the firewall-cmd above and allow 3389 from anywhere. ssh login will be Okay.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=3389/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

The only difference with the tutorial on the firewall-cmd is the LAN IP. What wrong with my firewall setting?

Comment: It looks that you are not in the same subnet specified in the firewall.

Comment: My IP address is 192.168.31.*. I am not familiar with firewall-cmd, but it seems like xrdp zone setting drops ssh network connection.

Comment: I guess the default firewall policy is the public zone and ssh is allowed in the public zone. After xrdp zone becomes the default zone, as ssh is not allowed in the xrdp zone, therefore ssh login is failed.